# ANull reference exception when I try to get assembly version info

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to get assembly version info in `<head>` section of master page. I have to do it in HTML section. This is row where I get null reference exception:

```
<script src="/MyViewCore.js?v=<% Response.Write( System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo( System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location ).FileVersion.Replace( ".", "" ) ); %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The isolated expression is:

```
System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo( 
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
)
    .FileVersion
    .Replace( ".", "" );
```

I can't figure out why this is problem.

Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: You need to narrow down which part of the object is null - it could be `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`, or `.FileVersion`. You should be able to do this in debug using breakpoints.

Comment: Split that bunch of code, `GetExecutingAssembly()` won't return `null` but `GetVersionInfo()` might and even if you have an object all its properties are optional. Not to mention that it may return a culture specific version info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo` is not made in a safe manner.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo(v=vs.110).aspx

The documentation for `GetVersionInfo` states it returns an object containing "only the name of the file requested" if it could not read any version information, which means the `FileVersion` property will be null.

> If the file did not contain version information, the FileVersionInfo contains only the name of the file requested.

Note that your code is unnecessarily verbose and calling `Response.Write` is  unnecessary because you can use the shorthand `<%=` (or the `<%:` syntax for automatic HTML encoding). You can also import namespaces using the `<%@ Import %>` directive.

If you're using C# 6.0 (Visual Studio 2015) I suggest using the null-safe operator `?.`.

Here's how I would do it:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Diagnostics" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Reflection" %>
<%
    String assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    FileVersionInfo versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo( assembly );
    String version = versionInfo.FileVersion?.Replace(".", "") ?? "someFallbackValue";
%>

...

<script src="/MyViewCore.js?v=<%: version %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm sure you'll agree that's considerably more readable and maintainable.